# Transpose indeterminate number of rows into columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have two tables with data, let's call them table T and table B.  Relevant data in T and B have a many-to-one relationship with each other, like this:

| T.id | B.code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1.2 |
| B | 1.2 |
| B | 1.5 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 15 |
| D | 296 |

etc.  (This is just a rough demonstration and doesn't resemble the actual data I'm using).

I've run a count(*) query and found that the most number of times items from table T appear in table B is 8.  What I want is to transpose the above table, which has thousands and thousands of entries in T and several hundred possible entries for B's corresponding value, into a 9-column table, like this:

| T.id | CODE 1 | CODE 2 | CODE 3 | CODE 4 | CODE 5 | CODE 6 | CODE 7 | CODE 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| B | 1.2 | 1.5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| C | 1 | 2 | 3 | 15 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| D | 296 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

etc.

The only search info I can find requires either manually joining B each time and excluding previous values of B.code (as I'm currently doing it), or using a PIVOT table (dynamic SQL or otherwise), which would necessarily have one column for each and every possible value of B.code (which, as mentioned, is several hundred values), neither of which are scalable options.

For reference, my code right now looks something like this:

```
SELECT
T.id,
b1.code as 'CODE 1', b2.code as 'CODE 2', b3.code as 'CODE 3', b4.code as 'CODE 4' (etc)
FROM T
LEFT JOIN B b1 ON b1.code = 
  (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM B WHERE B.t_id = T.id)
LEFT JOIN B b2 ON b2.code = 
  (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM B WHERE B.t_id = T.id AND B.code NOT IN (b1.code))
LEFT JOIN B b3 ON b3.code = 
  (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM B WHERE B.t_id = T.id AND B.code NOT IN (b1.code, b2.code))
LEFT JOIN B b4 ON b4.code = 
  (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM B WHERE B.t_id = T.id AND B.code NOT IN (b1.code, b2.code, b3.code))
```

What are my options?  Am I doomed?  There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: For some reason the tables aren't showing properly here, but they do when I hit edit.  How can I fix that?  EDIT: Thanks Aaron!

Comment: You need a proper CR/LF between the beginning/end of the table markdown and other text that's not part of the table. `etc.` was trying to be part of the table, but the structure didn't match, so _boom_.

Comment: Please provide the table definition for B and a few lines of sample data. Your code looks like doing the same thing as dynamique pivot in a more complicated way. Are there codes with no values?

Comment: Is the table `T` even relevant? If the same code/key is present in `B` do you even need to join? Or can you join _after_ you have pivoted?

Comment: @ Kendle I'm not sure how relevant that is; the only columns I ever reference in table B are the two listed in the first example table (though instead of T.id it would be B.t_id).  But there are two other columns: Seq (which is its own unique ID column) and Lead (which is either 1 or NULL).
@ AaronBertrand I can join after it's pivoted, since it's not strictly relevant to the pivoting itself.  I get plaintext data from there instead of a unique identifier.

Comment: And is `Code` a number, a string, something else? How do you define that `1` belongs in `Code 1` and `1.2` belongs in `Code 2`?

Comment: `Code` is a string.  The codes are swappable in order and are not prioritized, so however they're sorted internally in table B is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but perhaps this will help

```
Select *
 From (
        Select T.id
              ,B.Code
              ,Col = concat('Code ',row_number() over (partition by T.id order by B.code) )
         From T
         Join B on B.ID=T.ID
      ) src
 Pivot (max(Code) for Col in ([Code 1],
                              [Code 2],
                              [Code 3],
                              [Code 4],
                              [Code 5],
                              [Code 6],
                              [Code 7],
                              [Code 8]) ) pvt
```

Comment: @GabrielBenamy I should note:  If there are duplicate codes and you only want to show distinct values  (let's say A has two Codes = 1) use dense_rank() instead of row_number()

Answer (score 3):

The query you want to *end up* with is:

```
;WITH x AS 
 (
   SELECT [T.id], Code, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (PARTITION BY [T.id] ORDER BY @@SPID)
   FROM dbo.B
 ) SELECT [T.id], [CODE 1] = p.[1],[CODE 2] = p.[2], ... 
   FROM x
   PIVOT (MAX(Code) FOR rn IN 
   ([1],[2],...)) AS p;
```

But you need dynamic SQL to get there without having to hardcode `...Code 8` or add `Code 9` when another code gets added to the table:

```
DECLARE @sql     nvarchar(max) = N'',
  @outputColumns nvarchar(max),
  @pivotColumns  nvarchar(max),
  @maxCount      int = (SELECT MAX(c) FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.B GROUP BY [T.id]) AS c(c));

;WITH x(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1
  FROM x WHERE n < @maxCount)
SELECT @outputColumns = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('[CODE ',n,
                        '] = p.',QUOTENAME(n)), ','),
       @pivotColumns  = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(n), N',')
 FROM x;
 
 SELECT @sql = N';WITH x AS 
 (
   SELECT [T.id], Code, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY [T.id] ORDER BY @@SPID)
   FROM dbo.B
 ) SELECT [T.id], ' + @outputColumns + N' 
   FROM x
   PIVOT (MAX(Code) FOR rn IN 
   (' + @pivotColumns + N')) AS p;';
 
 EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output (from sample data in the question):

> | T.id | CODE 1 | CODE 2 | CODE 3 | CODE 4 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 | 1.2 | *null* | *null* |
> | B | 1.2 | 1.5 | *null* | *null* |
> | C | 1 | 2 | 3 | 15 |
> | D | 296 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8b119f5bf49eff6ef935529cbfe7188)